# Confused about Typescript Function Return Types

Tags: typescript, types

I am a bit confused about the following typescript code:

```js
function greet(name: string): string {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
}

function logGreeting(name: string): void {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}

function doSomething(name: string, callbackFn: (name: string) => void) {
    callbackFn(name);
}

doSomething('Zion', logGreeting);
doSomething('John', greet);
```

It is the last line of this code snippet that confuses me. In the `doSomething` function, I specify that `callbackFn` should take in `name`, which should be a `string`, and that it should return nothing (`void`).

But, in the `doSomething('John', greet)`, `greet` doesn't return `void`, and yet Typescript doesn't throw an error. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Returning something when nothing is expected is okay. The opposite not.

Comment: okay, thanks @tkausl!

Comment: could you provide it as an answer?

Comment: [Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is **my** interpretation of this behavior :

You're telling Typescript that you want a function which doesn't return anything by specifying `void` but you already know that. So Typescript doesn't care about what is returned by your callback, because - in the end - it won't allow you to use it.

If you change your expected return type to `string`, then you will get an error if your callback function doesn't return a `string`.

I wasn't aware of this behavior before I saw your question, so I made a test by changing the expected return type.

So the following code :

```
// I only changed your callback signature from void to string
function greet(name: string): string {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
}
   
function logGreeting(name: string): void {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}
    
function doSomething(name: string, callbackFn: (name: string) => string /* this is what I changed */) {
    callbackFn(name);
}
    
doSomething('Zion', logGreeting);
doSomething('John', greet);
```

Will return the following error :

```
est.ts:13:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(name: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(name: string) => string'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    
    13 doSomething('Zion', logGreeting);
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
    Found 1 error
```

So for me this behavior makes sense. Please tell me if my explanation was not clear enough, so that I can try to make it clearer.

**In a nutshell**, Typescript is not expecting to get a return value; so if your function returns something, Typescript won't throw an error, but you will not be allowed to use it!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Acuao! Yes, it was clear enough. 

Answer (score 1):

Think of a `void` return type as meaning that the return value can't be used. It doesn't really matter if it returns something or not, but typescript will not allow to use the return value if it's typed as `void`.

This allows you to pass pass function that might return a value as a function whose return value is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the short and brief answer @Alex Wayne! 